Bash completions with more than one word
My command is
thermostat.sh override off

I can get override to complete but not the subsequent off
Here is my script
#/usr/bin/env bash
_thermostat-completions() {
        if [ "${#COMP_WORDS[@]}" = "2" ]; then
                COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "off program hold override" "${COMP_WORDS[1]}"))
                return
        elif [ "${#COMP_WORDS[@]}" = "3" ]; then
                if [ "${COMP_WORDS[2]}" = "override" ]; then
                        # This was a guess; it doesn't work.
                        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "off holiday" "${COMP_WORDS[1]} ${COMP_WORDS[2]}"))
                        return
                fi
        fi
}

complete -F _thermostat-completions thermostat.sh

Is it possible to make a completion for the thrid word?
I don't understand what to do.

Did you try 1 instead of 2 as index? Indexing starts at 0. Not that that would be more recommended than the COMP_CWORD method.

For some reason ${COMP_WORDS[2]} doesn't work, but you can work around this by doing
prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
if [ "$prev" = "override" ]; then

So: what is wrong with ${COMP_WORDS[2]}?
Seems to need to be 1 not 2; both of these work.
#prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
prev="${COMP_WORDS[1]}"

